# How do I get the max and min values from a set of numbers entered?

Tags: java, max, min

Below is what I have so far:

I don't know how to exclude 0 as a min number though. The assignment asks for 0 to be the exit number so I need to have the lowest number other than 0 appear in the min string. Any ideas?

```
int min, max;

Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter a Value: ");
int val = s.nextInt();
min = max = val;

while (val != 0) {
  System.out.print("Enter a Value: ");
  val = s.nextInt();
  if (val < min) {
      min = val;
  }
  if (val > max) {
     max = val;
  }
};
System.out.println("Min: " + min);
System.out.println("Max: " + max);
```

Comment: `Math.min` and `Math.max` are what you are looking for

Comment: Simply have two variables, one called min one called max, and then check the entered variable to see if it is less than min or greater than max. If so, reset the variable.

Comment: Would they go inside the for or the if. Or outside the loop entirely?

Comment: Please play with your code, experiment, try. That's how you learn.

Comment: @ Hovercraft Full Of Eels Ok, that makes sense. I'll give that a go, thanks.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I'm to lazy for all that ;)

Comment: A few things that stick out:
1. Define what is a "number" that the user can enter. Doubles? Ints? Complex numbers?
2. You're assigning s.nextDouble() to an int. Why?
3. You're executing continue on the else block, Why?

Comment: @MadProgrammer: I'm sure that's what his instructors want him to do.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I have no doubt and your comment is a valid one, I'm just to lazy to re-invent the wheel ;)

Comment: Im so lost, can someone give me a hint for the Math.max and min. I am researching and its talking about arrays and I have never looked at that in class. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to keep track of a max value like this:

```
int maxValue = 0;
```

Then as you iterate through the numbers, keep setting the maxValue to the next value if it is greater than the maxValue:

```
if (value > maxValue) {
    maxValue = value;
}
```

Repeat in the opposite direction for minValue.

Comment: Best to nudge him and let him create the code. Otherwise you cheat him out of a decent learning experience.

Comment: I would still use Math.max/Math.min in this case (an "extra" assignment doesn't bother me) but it's probably not quite what the lesson is looking for.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I think we're safe with this one...don't think he'll forget this regardless of how he came to it. Besides, he still has to do the code for the minValue. =)

Comment: How would I assign the minValue, I dont know what number to assign it to. The user could enter 99999999999999999999999999999 and that could be the min, but i dont want to have 99999999999999999999999999999 in my code. Maybe the Math class would be better to use.

Comment: @user2934299 See [`Integer.MIN_VALUE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MIN_VALUE) (or for whatever appropriate type). However, note that the *most negative* (?) floating value (excluding infinity) is really [`-Double.MAX_VALUE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#MAX_VALUE).

Comment: Just set the minValue to the first value entered and update it only if a new value is less than the first value. Using Integer.MIN_VALUE would be horribly flawed.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a possible solution:

```
public class NumInput {
  public static void main(String [] args) {
    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (true) {
      System.out.print("Enter a Value: ");
      int val = s.nextInt();

      if (val == 0) {
          break;
      }
      if (val < min) {
          min = val;
      }
      if (val > max) {
         max = val;
      }
    }

    System.out.println("min: " + min);
    System.out.println("max: " + max);
  }
}
```

(not sure about using int or double thought)

Comment: Thankyou, it makes sense now. Cant believe I couldnt figure that out on my own. One question, for the first solution: Integer.MAX_INT; Integer.MIN_INT; are these final's? or some kind of java method?  sorry if its a stupid question, but im pretty new to all this.

Comment: @user2934299 They are constants. They represent, respectively, the maximum and the minimum number that a `int` can store.

Answer (score 2):

It is better

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.print("Enter numbers: ");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        double max = Double.MIN_VALUE;
        double min = Double.MAX_VALUE;

        while (true) {

            if ( !input.hasNextDouble())
                break;

            Double num = input.nextDouble();

            min = Math.min(min, num);
            max = Math.max(max, num);

        }
        System.out.println("Max is: " + max);
        System.out.println("Min is: " + min);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//for excluding zero
public class SmallestInt {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("enter number");
        int val=input.nextInt();
        int min=val;

        //String notNull;

        while(input.hasNextInt()==true)
        {
            val=input.nextInt();
            if(val<min)
                min=val;
        }
        System.out.println("min is: "+min);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did and it works try and play around with it. It calculates total,avarage,minimum and maximum.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   int[] score= {56,90,89,99,59,67};
   double avg;
   int sum=0;
   int maxValue=0;
   int minValue=100;

   for(int i=0;i<6;i++){
       sum=sum+score[i];
   if(score[i]<minValue){
    minValue=score[i];
   }
   if(score[i]>maxValue){
    maxValue=score[i];
   }
   }
   avg=sum/6.0;
System.out.print("Max: "+maxValue+"," +" Min: "+minValue+","+" Avarage: "+avg+","+" Sum: "+sum);}

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

here you need to skip int 0
like following:

```
val = s.nextInt();
  if ((val < min) && (val!=0)) {
      min = val;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.print("Enter a Value: ");
val = s.nextInt();
```

This line is placed in last.The whole code is as follows:-

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    int min, max;

    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a Value: ");
    int val = s.nextInt();
    min = max = val;

    while (val != 0) {
        if (val < min) {
            min = val;
        }
        if (val > max) {
            max = val;
        }
        System.out.print("Enter a Value: ");
        val = s.nextInt();

    }
    System.out.println("Min: " + min);
    System.out.println("Max: " + max);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to optimize solution by handling user input exceptions.

```js
public class Solution {
    private static Integer TERMINATION_VALUE = 0;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer value = null;
        Integer minimum = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        Integer maximum = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (value != TERMINATION_VALUE) {
            Boolean inputValid = Boolean.TRUE;
            try {
                System.out.print("Enter a value: ");
                value = scanner.nextInt();
            } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                System.out.println("Value must be greater or equal to " + Integer.MIN_VALUE + " and less or equals to " + Integer.MAX_VALUE );
                inputValid = Boolean.FALSE;
                scanner.next();
            }
            if(Boolean.TRUE.equals(inputValid)){
                minimum = Math.min(minimum, value);
                maximum = Math.max(maximum, value);
            }
        }
        if(TERMINATION_VALUE.equals(minimum) || TERMINATION_VALUE.equals(maximum)){
            System.out.println("There is not any valid input.");
        } else{
            System.out.println("Minimum: " + minimum);
            System.out.println("Maximum: " + maximum);
        }
        scanner.close();
    }
}
```