# Java - Smallest and Largest values

Tags: java, max, min

```
int min, max;

Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter a Value: ");
int val = s.nextInt();
min = max = val;

while (val != 0) {
  System.out.print("Enter a Value: ");
  val = s.nextInt();
  if (val < min) {
      min = val;
  }
  if (val > max) {
     max = val;
  }
};
System.out.println("Min: " + min);
System.out.println("Max: " + max);
  }
}
```

First of all this is a duplicate question, I really need an answer asap but noone is responding on the other question because it is old. That said;

The program I am supposed to create is supposed to take an infinite number of values until 0 is entered, then it displays the smallest and largest values entered. The way I have it set up now, the smallest is always 0. I need to figure out a way to somehow ignore 0 as the smallest number and get the next smallest. Any ideas?

Comment: Must be a class assignment. This has already come up today - http://stackoverflow.com/q/19671453/2864740

Comment: It is. Im sorry for the duplicate, I really need to get this done though, thanks!

Comment: Oh, *you* asked the other question too .. please *change the title* to reflect the actual problem. Anyway, simply *stop the loop* (e.g. with `break`) *before* doing the min/max logic when `0` is entered. Alternatively, use a guard (`if`) around the min-max logic so that it is skipped when the entered value is `0` and let the loop end through the normal termination condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about adding that to your loop conditions exactly as you say it?

```
while (val != 0) {
    System.out.print("Enter a Value: ");
    val = s.nextInt();
    if (val != 0) {
        if (val < min) {
            min = val;
        }
        if (val > max) {
            max = val;
        }
    } else {
         break;
    }
}
```

Comment: @user2934299 no problem...maybe accept this, or another answer since they are all pretty much the same, if it works as your answer?

Comment: Yea I will accept one, have to wait 5 minutes though.

Comment: @user2864740 I think that is more efficient, it requires only one comparison to the value, which will decrease run time.  While a minimal task, better to be optimal.

Answer (score 2):

This is one way of doing it.

```
while (true) {
  System.out.print("Enter a Value: ");
  val = s.nextInt();

  // stop the loop when 0 is entered (prevent min/max calculations)
  if(val == 0)
     break;

  if (val < min)
     min = val;
  if (val > max)
     max = val;
}
```

Comment: I like the use of `break` here. Which is surprising, because I very rarely use it.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
if (val < min) {
      min = val;
  }
```

to:

```
if ((val < min) && (val != 0)) {
      min = val;
  }
```

Comment: Wow, cant believe I didn't think of that, thankyou!

Comment: @user2934299 you may want to check if zero for the maximum value as well.

Comment: Yea, I will do that just to be safe.  Thanks again! and sorry for posting a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change condition as below and it shall work.

```
    if (val < min && val>0) {
            min = val;
        }
```