# Java program to find the largest & smallest number in n numbers without using arrays

Tags: java

I could get the largest without using arrays but, unable to get the smallest one.

```
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int smallest=0;
        int large=0; 
        int num;

        System.out.println("enter the number");

        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);

        int n=input.nextInt();

        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
          num=input.nextInt();
          if(num>large)
          {
           large=num;
          }
          System.out.println("the largest is:"+large);
          //gives the largest number in n numbers
```

code for the smallest..

```
     if(i==0&&num>0)
         small=num;
     if(num<small)
        small=num;
     System.out.println(small);

      }
```

Comment: Your code work for me after changing `small` to `smallest`.

Comment: You couldn't figure the condition for smallest number when you wrote that if block for largest number?

Comment: Your logic for the smallest will fail if all the input numbers are greater than zero. Your logic for the greatest will fail if all the input numbers are less than zero. You can fix this by initializing `smallest` and `large` to be the first number of the input.

Comment: I'm voting to close because of misleading title, problem partially caused by typo, and no examples of inputs and expected outputs (which could have also helped you discover your initialization/bounds mistake I mentioned above).

Comment: I didn't realize this earlier, but the end goal of this question is almost the same as [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19671453/11107541) which was asked just 4 months before this one, where it wouldn't have taken much adjustment to learn from. I would have voted to close as a duplicate if I had caught that earlier.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int smallest = 0;
    int large = 0;
    int num;
    System.out.println("enter the number");//how many number you want to enter
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = input.nextInt();
    num = input.nextInt();
    smallest = num; //assume first entered number as small one
    // i starts from 2 because we already took one num value
    for (int i = 2; i < n; i++) {
        num = input.nextInt();
        //comparing each time entered number with large one
        if (num > large) {
            large = num;
        }
        //comparing each time entered number with smallest one
        if (num < smallest) {
            smallest = num;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("the largest is:" + large);
    System.out.println("Smallest no is : " + smallest);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
int smallest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
   num=input.nextInt();
   if(num>large)
   {
       large=num;
   }
   if(num<smallest){
       smallest=num;
   }
```

Answer (score -5):

Try this...This simple

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class numbers
{
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
      int x, y, z;
      System.out.println("Enter three integers ");
      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

      x = in.nextInt();
      y = in.nextInt();
      z = in.nextInt();

      if ( x > y && x > z )
         System.out.println("First number is largest.");
      else if ( y > x && y > z )
         System.out.println("Second number is largest.");
      else if ( z > x && z > y )
         System.out.println("Third number is largest.");
      else   
         System.out.println("Entered numbers are not distinct");
   }
}
```

Answer (score -5):

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = 10;
        int j = 20;
        int k = 5;
        int x = (i > j && i > k) ? i : (j > k) ? j : k;
        int y = (i < j && i < k) ? i : (j < k) ? j : k;
        System.out.println("Largetst Number : "+x);
        System.out.println("Smallest Number : "+y);
    }
}
```

Output:
Largetst Number : 20
Smallest Number : 5

Answer (score -6):

Try the code mentioned below

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int smallest=0; int large=0; int num;
    System.out.println("enter the number");
    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
    int n=input.nextInt();
    num=input.nextInt();
    smallest = num;
    for(int i=0;i<n-1;i++)
        {
            num=input.nextInt();
            if(num<smallest)
            {
                smallest=num;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("the smallest is:"+smallest);
}
```

Answer (score -6):

@user3168844: try the below code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LargestSmallestNum {

    public void findLargestSmallestNo() {

        int smallest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int large = 0;
        int num;

        System.out.println("enter the number");

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int n = input.nextInt();

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {

            num = input.nextInt();

            if (num > large)
                large = num;

            if (num < smallest)
                smallest = num;

            System.out.println("the largest is:" + large);
            System.out.println("Smallest no is : "  + smallest);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String...strings){
        LargestSmallestNum largestSmallestNum = new LargestSmallestNum();
        largestSmallestNum.findLargestSmalestNo();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -6):

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LargestSmallestNum {

    public void findLargestSmallestNo() {

        int smallest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int large = 0;
        int num;

        System.out.println("enter the number");

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int n = input.nextInt();

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {

            num = input.nextInt();

            if (num > large)
                large = num;

            if (num < smallest)
                smallest = num;

            System.out.println("the largest is:" + large);
            System.out.println("Smallest no is : "  + smallest);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String...strings){
        LargestSmallestNum largestSmallestNum = new LargestSmallestNum();
        largestSmallestNum.findLargestSmalestNo();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -6):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LargestSmallestNumbers {

    private static Scanner input;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       int count,items;
       int newnum =0 ;
       int highest=0;
       int lowest =0;

       input = new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.println("How many numbers you want to enter?");
       items = input.nextInt();

       System.out.println("Enter "+items+" numbers: ");


       for (count=0; count<items; count++){
           newnum = input.nextInt();               
           if (highest<newnum)
               highest=newnum;

           if (lowest==0)
               lowest=newnum;

           else if (newnum<=lowest)
               lowest=newnum;
           }

       System.out.println("The highest number is "+highest);
       System.out.println("The lowest number is "+lowest);
    }
}
```