# Infinite loop with sentinel value and trying to get largest and smallest in java

Tags: java, sentinel

I wrote some code that asked the user to enter values, had a sentinel value of -99 and then displayed the largest and smallest value. It was working but displaying -99 as the smallest value. So I fiddled with it putting in a && != -99 for the smallest value but then I got an infinite loop happening, so I took that code out. But I must have deleted something vital because now it doesn't give me the largest and smallest it just goes into an infinite loop.

Could you please give me some pointers?

Here is my code;

```
public class Practice
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int smallest = 0; int largest = 0; int integer;

        // Create a Scanner object for keyboard input.
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter an integer: ");
        System.out.println("Enter -99 when finished.");
        System.out.println();

        int n = input.nextInt();
        integer = input.nextInt();
        smallest = integer; 

        while (integer != -99)
        {
            for(int i = 2; i < n; i++)
            {
                integer = input.nextInt();
                if(integer > largest)
                {
                    largest = integer;
                }
                if(integer < smallest)
                {
                    smallest = integer;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("The largest number is:" + largest);
        System.out.println("The smallest number is : "  + smallest);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not an infinite loop.  Your problem is that you've nested one loop within another, and you really only need one loop, not two.  I would strongly recommend that you step through this with a debugger - you'll see immediately what's going on.

Comment: `integer` is most certainly the worst name you can give to an `int` variable.

Comment: `float` or `double` are probably worse names

Comment: I second the comment to use a debugger to step through your code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JAVA- I need to get the max and min values from a set of numbers entered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19671453/java-i-need-to-get-the-max-and-min-values-from-a-set-of-numbers-entered)

Answer (score 0):

OK here's a few things (assuming I understand the goal of your program correctly):

```
public class Practice
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // I'm breaking these up to be a little more readable
        int smallest;
        int largest;
        // let's rename this something... not integer
        int userInt;

        // Create a Scanner object for keyboard input.
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Let's make the prompt a little more descriptive
        System.out.println("Enter some integers: ");
        System.out.println("Enter -99 when finished.");
        System.out.println();

        // Let's get rid of all these other variables and just get userInt
        userInt = input.nextInt();

        // To avoid doing anything else if we get -99 for the first number
        //  we'll test and exit accordingly.
        if (userInt == -99)
        {
            return;
        }

        smallest = userInt;
        largest = userInt;

        // Assuming we want to exit if the first number they enter is -99 we'll
        //  test before doing anything
        while (userInt != -99)
        {   
            // Note: this is not the cleanest, because we'll be wasting an
            //  iteration on data we've already stored in smallest & largest
            //  but it shouldn't hurt and I'm trying to minimize changes to
            //  your original structure.
            if(userInt > largest)
            {   
                largest = userInt;
            }
            if(userInt < smallest)
            {   
                smallest = userInt;
            }
            // Now that we've evaluated the first number entered we'll get
            //  the next number before we loop again so we'll be ready to see
            //  if we've hit an exit condition
            userInt = input.nextInt();
        }

        // This should be all you need to do, and after the loop is finished
        //  you can report.
        System.out.println("The largest number is:" + largest);
        System.out.println("The smallest number is : "  + smallest);
    }
}
```

Note that this still will not handle any exceptions, and may not be the cleanest overall approach, but I think it's more along the lines of what you're looking for.  (I made sure to avoid trying any exception catching approach, since I'm not sure if you've learned about those yet).

I'm really not sure what the purpose of the two nested loops was in your original code, since all you really wanted to do was keep asking for new values and evaluating them against the stored largest and smallest.

Nesting loops should usually only be done when you are dealing with multi-dimensional data.  Which you are certainly not doing here.

I was also confused with why you had some of those extra variables in there, so I strongly suggest ensuring that you can account for every single variable as you step through your code (either manually or with a debugger--and you should probably learn how to use the debugger).

Comment: Thanks for your comments but when I ran that code it made the smallest value 0 even though zero hadn't been entered.

Comment: Yeah, that'e because you initialized smallest and largest as 0 and never entered something smaller than 0.  It would be better to initialize smallest and largest with the first user inputed value.  I've made the appropriate edits, and tested them.
 (Note to self: don't post code on stack-overflow that you haven't tested, even if you need to run somewhere)

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for the nested `for` loop. You should be able to solve this problem with just a single `while` loop. When you fix this, you will likely find that you have more variables than you need.

Answer (score 0):

This will get rid of the issue of the min answer always returning a value of 0.

```
// Import all required packages
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Problem10
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // I'm breaking these up to be a little more readable
        int smallest = 999999999;
        int largest = 0;
        // let's rename this something... not integer
        int userInt;

        // Create a Scanner object for keyboard input.
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Let's make the prompt a little more descriptive
        System.out.println("Enter some integers: ");
        System.out.println("Enter -99 when finished.");
        System.out.println();

        // Let's get rid of all these other variables and just get userInt
        userInt = input.nextInt();

        // Assuming we want to exit if the first number they enter is -99 we'll
        //  test before doing anything
        while (userInt != -99)
        {   
            if(userInt > largest)
            {   
                largest = userInt;
            }
            if(userInt < smallest)
            {   
                smallest = userInt;
            }
            // Now that we've evaluated the first number entered we'll get
            //  the next number before we loop again so we'll be ready to see
            //  if we've hit an exit condition
            userInt = input.nextInt();
        }
        // This should be all you need to do, and after the loop is finished
        //  you can report.
        System.out.println("The largest number is:" + largest);
        System.out.println("The smallest number is : "  + smallest);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yup, that should fix it.  Though I think it'd be cleaner to initialize smallest & largest to the value of the first user input value.  But I'm sure this would work too.