# How to search max and min values in java

Tags: java

I coded a simple calculation and I need to know whether the code can be made more short and simple. And I need to get the max price and min price values too.

```
public class pro
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    { 
      Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.print("Enter price : ");
      int val1 = sc.nextInt();
      System.out.print("Enter price : ");
      int val2 = sc.nextInt();
      System.out.print("Enter price : ");
      int val3 = sc.nextInt();
      System.out.print("Enter price : ");
      int val4 = sc.nextInt();
      System.out.print("Enter price : ");
      int val5 = sc.nextInt();
      System.out.print("Total amount : " +(val1+val2+val3+val4+val5));
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you ever heard about **loops**?

Comment: If you see a repeating piece of code, try to make a method out of it, or put it inside a loop (or both).

Comment: Have you ever heard about arrays?

Comment: About min max values: Create a function and read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19671453/java-i-need-to-get-the-max-and-min-values-from-a-set-of-numbers-entered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get max value among your array by following:

```
int[] array;
int max;  
for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){  
  if(array[i] > max){  
    max = array[i];  
  }  
}  
System.out.println(max);
```

And to get minimum value you can do:

```
int[] array;
int min = array[0];  
for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){  
  if(array[i] < min){  
    min = array[i];  
  }  
}  
System.out.println(min);
```

Hope it solve your problem.

Comment: Appreciated! still I have a problem with min value. I entered the values I get the max correctly but min value is 0 always

Comment: @T.BHassim add int min = array[0]; in above code and it will work.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not doing your homework (or your thinking!) for you, but here are a couple of hints.

1. Use arrays.
2. To find that largest (or smallest) value in an array, you need to use a loop.

Comment: Of course you are! Remember, it is beginning of new school year, and this task looks like simple first homework in programming course

Comment: @Andremoniy - Ermm ... how am I doing the OP's homework for him?

Answer (score 1):

```
int[] prices = new int[5];
int totalAmount = 0;

for(int i=0; i < prices.length; ++i)
{
    System.out.print("Enter price : ");
    prices[i]=sc.nextInt();
    totalAmount += prices[i];
}

System.out.print("Total amount : " + totalAmount);
```

Enjoy

Comment: What is the "value[i]"?

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
int value[] = new int[5];
for(int i=0 ; i<value.length; i++) {  
  value[i] = sc.nextInt();
}
```

For finding the max and min, maintain two variable, int min and int max initialise with say value[0] and value[1], start iterating from i=2 to the value.length. As you iterate update these values by comparing with value[i].

Answer (score 0):

Place your values in arrays (FIND OUT HOW, YOUR WORK).Then
You need to use a sort technique.
This one here is effective, use this code but please understand it.

```
public void sort(int a[]){
int b[] = a.clone();
for(int i = 0; i < b.length; i++){
for(int c = i + 1; c < b.length; c++){
if(b[i] > b[c]){
b[i] = b[i] + b[c];
b[c] = b[i] - b[c];
b[i] = b[i] + b[c];
}
}
```

Max value is at last index and min value is at index position 0(You must figure how to get it out or you learn nothing). This sort, sorts values in ascending order. To make it sort in descending order just change the greater than sign to less than sign in the f.f.g line:

```
if(b[i] > b[c]){
```

Comment: You DO NOT need to sort the array to find the min and max values.

Answer (score 0):

To get the maximum value:

```
 // getting the maximum value
    public static int getMaxValue(int[] array){  
          int maxValue = array[0];  
          for(int i=1;i < array.length;i++){  
            if(array[i] > maxValue){  
              maxValue = array[i];  
            }  
         }  
         return maxValue;  
    }
```