# How do I pull out the max and min of the given numbers or improve this in general?

Tags: java, max, min, minimum

I'm not the brightest when it comes to coding. In fact, I spent my whole last semester on Python and now I'm on Java. It's sort of a whole new world for me. I barely remember Python because we barely used it. Now I'm assigned something from a professor that isn't exactly the brightest either.

Could I get a little help on this? I'm trying to make it so that it pulls out the minimum and maximum from the inputted responses.

```
/**
 * Auto Generated Java Class.
 */
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Assignment1 {


  public static void main(String[] args) { 

    double number1;
    double number2;
    double number3;
    double number4;
    double number5;
    double number6;
    double number7;
    double number8;
    double number9;
    double number10; 
    int min = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int max = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter number 1:");
    number1 = keyboard.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("Enter number 2:");
    number2 = keyboard.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("Enter number 3:");
    number3 = keyboard.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("Enter number 4:");    
    number4 = keyboard.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("Enter number 5:");
    number5 = keyboard.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("Enter number 6:");
    number6 = keyboard.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("Enter number 7:");
    number7 = keyboard.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("Enter number 8:");
    number8 = keyboard.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("Enter number 9:");
    number9 = keyboard.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("Enter number 10:");
    number10 = keyboard.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("Your minimum is " + min);
    System.out.println("Your maximum is " + max);  
  }


}
```

Comment: Have you covered arrays and/or loops yet?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JAVA- I need to get the max and min values from a set of numbers entered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19671453/java-i-need-to-get-the-max-and-min-values-from-a-set-of-numbers-entered)

Comment: Set the minimum to the first value. After each nextDouble(), compare the value to the minimum. If it's lower then set that as the new minimum. Then repeat for each input. Do the same steps for the maximum.

Answer (score 0):

First, I suggest you define and assign values to your variables on the same line. Second, start with the min equal to the max possible value and the max equal to the min possible value (and they should be `double` not `int`). Something like,

```
System.out.println("Enter number 1:");
double number1 = keyboard.nextDouble();
System.out.println("Enter number 2:");
double number2 = keyboard.nextDouble();
double min = Math.min(number1, number2);
double max = Math.max(number1, number2);
System.out.println("Enter number 3:");
double number3 = keyboard.nextDouble();
min = Math.min(min, number3);
max = Math.max(max, number3);
// ...
```

Of course, if you can use loops then you might write

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
double min = Double.MAX_VALUE;
double max = Double.MIN_VALUE;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    System.out.printf("Enter number %d:%n", i + 1);
    double num = keyboard.nextDouble();
    min = Math.min(min, num);
    max = Math.max(max, num);
}
System.out.println("Your minimum is " + min);
System.out.println("Your maximum is " + max);
```