# Java - method that returns lowest integer from parameter

Tags: java

I have a method that takes 4 integers/numbers as a parameter, and I want the method to return the lowest number from the parameter. How do I do this?

Comment: This sounds like homework. What have you tried already?

Comment: Probably by writing some code?

Comment: `Math.min(Math.min(a,b), Math.min(c,d))`

Comment: [`Math.min`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#min-int-int-) is your friend

Comment: Simple solution if you don't care about performance: `IntStream.of(a, b, c, d).min()`.

Comment: @Bubletan I am pretty sure that anything that has "stream" in its name is not a "simple" solution for a person asking such kind of questions.

Comment: Even without `Math.min(int, int)`, you could create your own `min(int... values)` that would simply iterate the varargs and return the minimum value. This is a simple loop

Comment: There's https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19671453/java-i-need-to-get-the-max-and-min-values-from-a-set-of-numbers-entered but..

Answer (score 0):

```
public int example (int tall1, int tall2, int tall3, int tall4) {

    int lowest = Math.min(tall1,tall2);
    int lowest1 = Math.min(tall3, tall4);
    int lowest2 = Math.min(lowest,lowest1);

    return lowest2;
}
```

This worked!